# window.location.href don't work with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

For some reason, the "**window.location.href**" function does not work for me, can't seem to find out why.
**This is the code from index.php:**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div style="width: 300px;">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="email"  name="email" required />
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password"  name="password" required />
                <p><br/></p>
                <a href="#">Forgotten Password</a><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="login" id="login" value="Login">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And this is the function in the "action.php" file that is mentioned in the jQuery function:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["userLogin"])){
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["userEmail"]);
    $password = md5($_POST["userPassword"]);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
    $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if($run_query===false){
        echo mysqli_error($con);
    } else {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query);
        $_SESSION["uid"]= $row["user_id"];
        $_SESSION["name"]= $row["first_name"];
        echo "welcome";
    }
}
?>
```

**This is the jQuery with the AJAX function:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var email =  $("#email").val();
        var pass = $("#password").val();
        
        $.ajax({
            url : "action.php",
            method : "POST",
            data : {userLogin: 1, userEmail:email, userPassword:pass},
            success : function(data){
                if(data == "welcome"){
                    window.location.href = "profile.php";
                }
               /* alert(data);*/
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**notes:**
As you can see in the jQuery function, there is this: "alert(data);". I wanted to look if it does work and put it on the screen without the "window.location.href" function to see that the "if" statement is correct, and it does work. Further more, when I go directly to the profile.php file, I see That the user is logged in, which means for me that the SQL functions is working fine, just it will not Re-Direct me to that (profile.php) page.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois no, you don't. If you do `window.location.href = "/subdir"` right now, you'd be taken to `http://stackoverflow.com/subdir`

Comment: I think him missing the forward slash is what is causing the error.

Comment: You failed to test if your if statement was working.

Comment: Before coming here and posting a question titled "window.location.href isn't working", you should have taken that line and pasted it directly into your console, thus proving that it is in fact working. Then you go back to the drawing board and figure out what actually isn't working.

Comment: Most likely `if(data == "welcome")` is false because you (maybe) inadvertently printed some white-space in the php file. Try trimming the ajax result before checking == "welcome": `if($.trim(data) == "welcome")`

Comment: @KevinB The if statement is working.

Comment: Then i can't recreate your problem. `window.location.href = "profile.php"` takes me from `mydomain.com/whatever.php` to `mydomain.com/profile.php`

Comment: @KevinB Exactly why im going bit crazy here. Im trying to go from mydomay.com to mydomain.com/profile.php and it just not working for me. and oter reason why?

Comment: @GrowingDev How do you _know_ that the `if` statement is working? The alert that you currently have in your code above is _outside_ of your `if` statement, which means that it will _always_ run.

Comment: No, there's no reason it shouldn't be working. check your console for errors. If the alert fires, and moving it to inside the if statement still causes the alert, your page should be redirecting or throwing an obvious error into the console.

Comment: I cant belive im helpless because of this. i must be not seeing something here. because the alert fires as i said, just the redirection wont.

Comment: And has been pointed out, your alert has no connection whatsoever to whether or not you are actually going inside the `if` statement. If you put your alert directly before the redirect, you will likely see that the alert does not fire.

Comment: F12 opens your console, if you still haven't.

Comment: Of course i did it my friend, nothing screams out.

Answer (score -1):

`window.location.href` expects an absolute url or a url relative to your domain (if it starts with a `/`).

If you only want to change the file part of your current path, you can use `window.location.assign("profile.php")`

Comment: Isn't this only required when you are sending to a different host?

Comment: No. You don't need an absolute path. You do need a starting `/` for a relative one, but that's it.

Comment: That depends. When I'm on `www.example.com/foo/bar` and use `window.location.href = "/baz"`, I will be redirected to `www.example.com/baz`. If I want to go to `www.example.com/foo/bar` I would either use `window.location.href = "/foo/baz` or `window.location.assign("baz")`

Comment: Yeah, it's relative to the domain name.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to redirect inside same domain

```
window.location.href = "/profile.php";
```

If you want to redirect to another domain

```
window.location.href = "http://www.antotherdomainname.com/profile.php";
```

Comment: No. You don't need the full URL. Can we stop with that?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, It is not necessary to put the full url if you are redirecting inside your domain. But if you are redirecting to another domain (website) then it is must to put the full url. Am I right?

Comment: @BiswajitPanday right, but that's clearly not what is happening here.